# How to edit the commit date when using git commit --reedit-message?

Tags: git, git-commit

I recently used `git commit --reedit-message=HEAD`, to make a new commit while using most of the text from the HEAD. All went well till I observed that after committing, the new commit showed the same date stamp as the previous HEAD.

The log (pretty) looked like this

```
hash   , auth date , message
86fb360, 2019-11-16, copied commit (committed on 2019-11-21)
6dc9583, 2019-11-16, original commit (committed on 2019-11-16)
```

The basic log command `git log -1`also showed the old date.

Why did this happen?

How to make the actual commit date appear on the new commit when using the above command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git commit -c @ --reset-author
```

[`--reset-author`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt---reset-author) renews the author information including timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

That's to be expected.

From `-C <commit>` [section](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt--Cltcommitgt) in the doc :

> Take an existing commit object, and reuse the log message and the authorship information (**including the timestamp**) when creating the commit.

*(emphasis mine)*

then the `-c` / `--reedit-message` references it with "Like -C, but ..."

---

Depending on your exact needs, what you could probably do is to `--amend` that last commit and set whatever date/author or other metadata you want. If you *don't* alter anything though, note that the committer date will still be the moment you do the amending, not the original date, which hopefully is what you tried to obtain?